# How to print an image in iOS 4.2?

Tags: ios, image, printing

I find the Apple documentation difficult to read through.  Perhaps someone out there is willing to share some code on how to easily print a JPG or PNG file in iOS 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic steps:

1. Instantiate an `NSData` object from your file.
2. Create a `UIPrintInfo` object that contains the job specs.
3. Send the data to a `UIPrintInteractionController`, which will begin the process.

See [this article](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67176-airprint-tutorial-simple-print-file-30-lines-code.html) for a code sample.